# jQuery Find and Replace Element in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

There is HTML as a string returned by Ajax call.

```
headings
....
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
</div>
....
```

I'm retrieving the `.wrapper` and input element

```
var elements = $(MY_HTML_STRING);
var domName = $('input[name="name"]', elements);
```

then making updates with both of them, and, my question is how to put them back into `MY_HTML_STRING` for further sending with ajax to different recipient.

Please let me know if it will be better to do with regex.

**UPDATE:**

Updates are: input value updating + `.wrapper` class updates and writing a piece of data into global variable. Everything can be done with regex, but I like the jQuery smoothness of code. The question is technically: if it's possible in the way I suggested.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. What kind of updates are you making to them and what are they when you're finished updating them?

Comment: Please check my updates.

Answer (score 1):

After you've made your updates you can simply do something like the following (assuming there is only one `div.wrapper` that you're working with and that it is unique):

```
MY_HTML_STRING.replace(/<div class="wrapper">.*?<\/div>/, $('.wrapper').html());
```

Then you can make another AJAX call and pass the string back to the server.

Comment: Great answer, but i'm making `.wrapper` class updates, while `$('.wrapper').html()` return inner HTML. Lets forget about the `.wrapper` for now. Is there a way to update input value and put it back into the HTML string not using regex?

Comment: 1. You could do `$('.wrapper').clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html()` to include the wrapper HTML in a "hackish" sense. 2. Short answer, not really. If the original inner contents may vary then RegEx is the *only* solution. Why would you be strongly opposed against RegEx though? It's awesome!